# How to create equivalent LEFT JOIN query in Django's ORM (1.11)

Tags: python, sql, django

With the following model setup (simplified for brevity):

```
class Claim(models.Model):
    permalink = models.SlugField(max_length=255, blank=True, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), db_index=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    collaborators = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model(), through='ClaimCollaborator', related_name='claims')
    # ...other fields

class ClaimCollaborator(models.Model):
    claim = models.ForeignKey(Claim, db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # ...other fields
```

I am trying to replicate the following SQL query in Django's ORM.

```
SELECT *
FROM claim c
LEFT JOIN claim_collaborator cc ON cc.claim_id = c.id
WHERE c.permalink = 'foo-bar'
AND (c.author_id = 2 OR cc.user_id = 2)
```

The logic I believe should be straightforward with usage of `django.db.models.Q`, but the bit I'm struggling on is the LEFT JOIN. Bit of a Django ORM noob, and I have attempted various usage of select_related() with the ClaimCollaborators model to no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django will do the join automatically:

```
claims = Claim.objects.filter(Q(permalink='foo-bar') & (Q(author_id=2) | Q(claimcollaborator__user_id=2)))
```

Comment: It does not result to a `LEFT JOIN`. Anyone have this issues?